# Best way to improve the database performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, optimization

I was recently in an interview and i have been asked a question that was :
After one year of publishing your application the data in the database became massive , so what is the best way to optimize the DB performance in the DB side not in the coding side whether database is Oracle or SQL server ... i just want to know what is the best answer for this question ?

Comment: Depends on the database. Partitioning can be a good safe bet. Better indexing. Possibly archiving older data. Pre-aggregating data, if possible. This is one of those questions that has a lot of answers and is probably more geared towards understanding if you know that or not (or can at least cough up one or two reasonable methods).

Comment: There is no "best answer".  What there is is a series of questions which need to be asked.  As @JNevill suggests the interviewer has presented a nice open-ended question which allows you to demonstrate the breadth and depth of your understand of databases and performance tuning.

Answer (score 4):

I can give you an answer, but can't guarantee that an interviewer would like it.

The best way to optimise the performance is to understand what your application does, and the data structures that the system provides. You must understand the business so that you can understand the data, and when you do that you'll know whether the SQL submitted to the system is "asking the correct question", and doing so in a way that makes sense for the data and it's distribution.

Furthermore, you should measure and document what the normal behaviour of the system is, and the cycles it might go through on a daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly and annual basis. You should be prepared to be able to quantify any deviation from normal performance.

You must understand the database technology itself. The concepts, the memory structures and processing, REDO, UNDO, index and table types, and maybe partitioning, parallelism, and RAC. The upsides and the downsides.

You must know SQL extremely well, and be completely up to date on its capabilities in your DB version, and any new ones now available. You must be able to read a raw execution plan straight from DBMS_XPlan(). Tracing query execution must be within your skill set.

You must understand query transformation and optimisation, the use of bind variables, and statistics.

If I had to choose only one of the above, it would be that you must have measured and documented historical performance, and be able to quantify deviations from it, because without that you will never know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the point of the question was to see how you deal with vague, overly broad questions.  One thing you did that was pretty positive, was to seek out authoritative answers on SO.  Don't know if that's going to help you now that the interview is done.

So - how do you respond to such a question?  An "I have no way of knowing" is probably not the approach to take - even if it the correct answer.

Maybe something like, "I'm not entirely sure what you're asking - so let me try to understand with a couple of questions.  Are we talking about query performance or update performance?   Are there indexes to support the workload?  What makes you feel optimization is necessary?"

I think it is as much about your approach to problem solving as any particular tech.

But, then on the other hand, maybe I'm wrong.  Maybe the first answer is always "Index the hell out of it!"  :-D

Interviewing is a nightmare, isn't it?

Comment: Better this kind of question than the typical gotcha: "What is the syntax for <some obscure xml operation in a relational database that the questioner knows and thinks very few others do> ?", to which the only decent answer is "I'd look it up in the documentation. It's something like this ...". My Oracle interview question was always: "What factors affect whether an index is used as part of an execution plan". Nice and open ended.

Comment: @DavidAldridge, I was thinking as I was driving home last night that this is a great question. If you are unexperienced at DB stuff, then this question doesn't seem open ended. It seems like it has a single correct answer. Furthermore it will show whether you are somewhat familiar with database optimization, or very experienced. It's a great interview question if you are looking for a front end developer that needs to have solid database skills.

Comment: @JNevill Yes, I think the art of the good question is that it should let the person expand at will on the topic, or just give a simplistic answer. Experience always comes through in the answer, if the question is open ended enough.